# CSS - Unable to center text vertical and horizontally

Tags: html, css

I have a text that I want to center. I've googled it and I tried some techniques, such as table display, but none of them works.

The nearest I've been to center it, is with the following CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    width: 500px;
    top: 45%;
    left: 30%;
}
```

With trial and error...

And, of course, depending on the screen, the error is more, or less evident.

Comment: To center align text horizontally, an option is to use the rule `text-align: center`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS3's `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` after you set your element at `top:50%; left: 50%;`

```css
.absoluteCenter{
  background:red;
  padding:24px;

  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="absoluteCenter">HELLO WORLD</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

try the following:

```
#wrapper{
//all of the other properties
text-align:center // should center your text

}
```